# Windows Phone 8.1 App dont see DataType property in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, datatemplate

I created new Windows Phone 8.1 project and when I try to set [DataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) , vs2013 give me in editor error: `The property 'DataType' was not found in type 'DataTemplate'`. In WPF application I dont have this problem. How to fix it?

This is my MainPage.xml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App6.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App6"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Employee}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*DataType* is not supported in WinRT XAML - see [DataTemplate Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#properties). You can also find this information [here at this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c5c40014-6f7f-4287-9a45-dc978c0dccb8/set-contentcontrolcontent-to-an-object-unable-to-activate-windows-tailored-application?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Maybe [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) will help you, here is some help: [one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryanbolling/archive/2012/12/08/how-to-control-the-datatemplateselector-in-windows-store-apps.aspx), [two](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector), [three](https://leeontech.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/using-datatemplateselector-in-metro-style-app/).

Answer (score 0):

DataType is not supported in WinRT XAML (Universal app), Windows Phone 8

To use different template for each type you have to [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)